# Meteor + React, show specific content based on user’s actions

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm working on an app that contains send/cancel request functionality.
I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Events } from '../../api/collections/events.js';
import { Visitors } from '../../api/collections/visitors.js';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Event extends Component {
    handleDelete() {
        Event.remove(this.props.event._id);
    }
    requestInvite() {
        let eid = Events.findOne(this.props.event._id).title;
        Visitors.insert({
            visitor_id: Meteor.userId(),
            visitor_email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
            event_name: eid,
        })
        // did it to debug function, returns correct value
        console.log(Visitors.findOne({id: this._id}) + ', ' + Meteor.userId());
    }
    cancelInvite() {
        Visitors.remove(this.props.visitor._id);
    }
    render() {
        const visitor = this.props.visitor.visitor_id;
        const length = Visitors.find({}).fetch().length;
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.event.owner == Meteor.userId() ?
                <div>
                    <img src={this.props.event.picture} />
                    <span>{this.props.event.title}</span>
                    <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
                </div> 
            </div> :
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src={this.props.event.picture} />
                        <span>{this.props.event.title}</span>
            <div>
                            { length > 0 && visitor == Meteor.userId() ?
                                <button onClick={this.cancelInvite.bind(this)}>Cancel Request</button>
                                :
                                <button onClick={this.requestInvite.bind(this)}>Request invite</button>
                            }
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Event.propTypes = {
    event: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        event: Events.findOne({id: this._id}) || {},
        visitor: Visitors.findOne({id: this._id}) || {},
    };
}, Event)
```

It works quite simple, this component shows action buttons depend on user's status (if the current user hosts this event, it shows `delete` related functionality and so one, I just keep is as simple as it can be for this example). If the current user isn't this event's hoster, component lets this user to send (and cancel) a request for invite. Okay, everything works as it should but only for the first user clicked on `Send Request` button and after that ich changes to `Cancel Request` (I use different browsers to test cases like this). The rest of users can also click on `Send Request` but for them it doesn't change to `Cancel Request` (but it still adds correct document to `Visitors` collection, also I have a component which displays all the visitors and the data is corret, i.e ids, emails and event titles). By the first time I thought it's an issue with `findOne` function, but I don't think so because `console.log(Visitors.findOne({id: this._id}) + ', ' + Meteor.userId());`'s  output stays correct giving me current user's id and just created visitor's id which are the same for each case. Also I found a very strange behaviour. When the app rebuilds, send/cancel functionality works as it suppossed to for every single user.
I think I'm kinda close for the solution but need a little gotcha to do it.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

**UPD**

It's obvious that my question isn't full without describing `Visitor` document being created in this component. Here it is:

```
{
  "_id": "Qbkhm9dsSeHyge4rT",
  "visitor_id": "qunyJ4sXNfz2w8qeR",
  "visitor_email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
  "event_name": "test",
}
```

So as you can see I grab `visitor_id` from `Meteor.userId()` and that's why I'm using `this.props.visitor.visitor_id` to check if currently logged in user's id is equal to a particular visitor's id.

**Solution**

The problem was with my query to fetch visitor's ids in `createContainer` function. I changed it to `visitor = Visitors.findOne({visitor_id: Meteor.userId()})` and it worked the way I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your `Visitors` collection documents are structured, it's difficult to say for sure; however, it seems that your condition for `visitor == Meteor.userId()` is the issue since you said that the documents are correctly being added to the `Visitors` collection, which would make `length > 0` return `true`.

The issue could be that you are setting `const visitor = this.props.visitor.visitor_id;` rather than say `const visitor = this.props.visitor._id;`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!
I updated my question by attaching document's schema. So you see that I'm trying to compare visitor's id to a current user's id which eventually changes buttons but for only the user who tapped "Send Request" button first.

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure it has to do with `visitor == Meteor.userId()` not matching. What do you get if you console.log `visitor` right after you declare `const visitor`?

Comment: Console.log gives me the first visitor's id, i.e the first user tapped "Request invite" button. When I logged in as another user and hit this button, console doesn't logs my current id, it logs previous user id.

Comment: How are your Events collection documents structured? In your export statement at the bottom of your code snippet, you are querying the visitors collection and looking for a document that has an `id` that is equal to the `_id` of the Event. And actually, you don't even have an `id` field in your Visitors collection.

Comment: I think you want to change your Visitors collection query to something like: `Visitors.findOne({visitor_id: Meteor.userId(), event_name: this.event_name})`. Where `this.event_name` would be the field name of the event name in your Events collection. This will give you only visitors that have the current user's id AND a record containing the current Event name.